# linear gradient in asp.net doesn't work in IE6 to IE8

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer-8, linear-gradients

the code in bellow doesn't work in IE6 to IE8

```
 background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, white 0%, gray 50%, black 100%);
```

I add the bellow code to my css until linear gradient displays in IE8 but this works in IE10 but doesn't work in IE6 to IE8

```
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, white 0%, gray 50%, black 100%);
```

what can I do until the linear gradient with 45 deg is displayed to IE8?

Answer (score 1):

IE8 and earlier do not support standard CSS `linear-gradient` (not even with a `-ms-` prefix).

IE9 also doesn't support them.

This is well known and well documented.

There are `filter` styles that you can use instead ([see here for more info](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient)), or you can use a library like [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/), which attempts to add support for the standard CSS feature to older IE versions.

If you don't want to use any javascript code, then use the `filter` styles.

However my recommendation would be to use the CSS3Pie JS library, because the `filter` styles have a number of known bugs and glitches which can catch you out, and because it's easier to work with the more standard CSS code that CSS3Pie provides.

Hope that helps.

Comment: but I can't give 45deg with filter. I use filter but I can't give that 45 deg. the gradient with filter is top to bottom or left to right or versa

Comment: that's why I recommend CSS3Pie instead; the `filter` styles are quite limited.